# If $ z,w \in \mathbb{C} $ show that $ (z,w) $ is L.D iff $ im(z \bar{w}) = 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

This is not a duplicate. I recently asked for an approach to the question. Now I have made some attempts and would like some suggestions as to where I'm going wrong.

We write $ z = a+bi $ and $ w = c +di $

Hence $ z \bar{w} = (ac + bd) + i(-ad+bc) \space $    and $ im(z \bar{w}) = -ad+bc $

and so $ im(z \bar{w}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow bc = ad $

So we must prove that $ (z,w) $ is Linearly Dependant $ \Leftrightarrow bc = ad $

Or prove that $ (z,w) $ is Linearly Independent $ \Leftrightarrow bc \neq ad $

i.e -

$  \exists $    $ x,y \in \mathbb{R}   $  such that  $ xz + yw = 0 \Rightarrow x=y=0  \Leftrightarrow bc \neq ad$

From this point onwards I have been just trying to manipulate all the variables till I proved the above statement true but I have gotten nowhere.

I'm starting to doubt myself that the above statement is true at this stage. Could someone confirm that it is or isn't. If it is could that someone show me how to prove it, and if it isn't could that someone explain to me where I've gone wrong and what should be done.

Thanks, this has been annoying me for a while now.

Note: $ im(q) = $ imaginary part of q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking real and imaginary parts:
$$ xz+yw=0 \iff xa+yc = 0 \text{ and } xb+yd = 0. $$
Rewriting these two as a matrix equation,
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 0, $$
and this has nonzero solutions for $x$ and $y$ if and only if
$$ \det \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} = ad-bc \neq 0. $$

Comment: It's so simple.. I Love it !!